# sapjco3.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: sapjco3

I'm using Tomcat 9 with jdk8.I have only 1 webapp deployed on the Tomcat server. Sapjco3.jar and dll placed in WEB-INF\lib of webapps or in Tomcat\lib folder.
Come what may this error doesn't go?
What can be the cause?  Tried all the options found on stackoverflow questions.
Nothing works.

Comment: Also wanted information on who loads the sapjco3.dll. Is it the sapjco3.jar?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer is within the product's documentation itself.
In the JCo 3.1.3 installation documentation it says:

> When using JCo within an application server, you need to ensure that
> the JCo library is only loaded once. This is achieved best by putting
> the sapjco3.jar file into the system classpath or into the startup
> classpath of the application server itself. If JCo is loaded twice by
> different classloaders, this also results in the JCo native library to
> be loaded twice, which will fail. As a consequence, an application
> must never package JCo within its own deployment unit. It has to
> presume that it is already installed and provided in the respective
> runtime.